# Can't change MAC address on Rooted Android Nextbook Ares 8

Tags: privacy, root-access, mac-address

I rooted my Nextbook Ares 8" tablet, model NXA8QC116, so I could change the MAC address and host name, as I hate personal data mining and user behavior monitoring.

Device specifics: Model NXA8QC116S, Android Version : 5.1.1, Build # : V3.0.?

Rooted with the binary "Nextbook Ares 8 Stock 5.1.1 Rom modified boot.img" from forum.xda-developers.com

Commands (terminal app):

```
u0_xxx@NXA8QC116:/ $: su
root@NXA8QC116:/ #: busybox iplink show wlan0
[reports the MAC address]
root@NXA8QC116:/ #: busybox ifconfig wlan0 hw ether fa:8e:f0:f2:14:27
root@NXA8QC116:/ #: busybox iplink show wlan0
[reports the original, unchanged MAC address]
```

I tried this with the WiFi both on and off.  I also tried leaving "busybox" out of the commands.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you also tried `ip link set wlan0 fa:8e:f0:f2:14:27`?

Comment: I tried that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm trying to locate a thread I saw somewhere where you find the right file, change the MAC with a hex editor, and reboot the device.  This apparently worked on a couple of other devices, maybe it will work on this one.

Comment: I don't see any nvram files in the data, etc, or wifi directories on this device, so I'm out of ideas.  I used Total Commander to look at the directories, after setting it so "show hidden files" and enabling "root functions everywhere."

Comment: There are no /*nvram*/ files on this device, so that method is not applicable.  I searched for files with Total Commander, after setting it so "show hidden files" and enabling "root functions everywhere."  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: `nvram` is usually not a file but a partition/data section in your flash chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a file called mac.txt in /config/wifi, which contains the MAC address, which is the only thing in the file.

Changing this value, and then enabling the wifi adapter results in a new MAC address.  (Confirmed by logging into a router it connected to.) This change survives a reboot.

Now to research how to write a script to randomly pick a manufacturer prefix number and the rest of the digits at every restart, along with setting a temporary randomized hostname (setprop net.hostname xxxxxx).

I found the MAC text file by searching the device for files with Total Commander.